# Perl is loading as plain text in browser

Tags: html, css, perl, cgi

So, this was working fine two minutes ago and for some reason It has now stopped working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Dan Edwards


open (FILE, "donations.txt") || &ErrorMessage;
@filemessages = <FILE>;
close (FILE);

print <<EndHTML;


Content-type: text/html
<html>
<head>
<title>Teenage Cancer Research Charity Donations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sponsor.css\">


</head>\
<body >
<div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <h1><center>Teenage Cancer Research</center></h1>
        </div>


  <div id="nav">

  </div>



  <div id="aside">

  </div>

        <div id="welcome">
            <h1>Welcome to the Teenage Cancer Research Donations Page<h1>




        </div>






<div id="donationsTable">
EndHTML

$n=0;
print "<UL><H2>Below are the Current Donations</H2></UL>";
foreach $message (@filemessages) {
    print "<LI><I>$message</I>\n"; 
    $n++;
}

print<<EndHTML;
<br>
<br>

<h1>Please dig deep and give whatever you can!</h1>
<br>
<a href="donate.html" class="button"/>SPONSOR ME!</a>

</div>




<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="totalTable">
<table class="center" border="1">
<tr><th>Total Donated Online</th>
<td>£</td>
<th>Gift Aid Plus Supplement</th>
<td>£</td>
</tr>



</table>
</div>

  <div id="footer">
Copyright © Teenage Cancer Research
</div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>

EndHTML
```

It finds the file and opens the page, but it loads as plain text. I am totally stuck and have no idea what to do.

I am a complete Perl novice and I dont have a clue why its not working

Comment: Please tell me that there isn't really a charity that is running on code like this?

Comment: No its not, this is for a personal project.. dont worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
Content-type: text/html
<html>
```

You need an extra line after the `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1):

[AddHandler](http://editrocket.com/articles/perl_apache_windows.html)
You need to make sure the web server is configured to execute the code correctly.

Answer (score -3):

Fixed, Resorting back to PRINT on every line.